# Operating on images in emgucv

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have 2 Emgu.CV.Image images:

```
Image<Gray, byte> img1 = new Image<Gray, byte>(@"xyz.gif");
Image<Gray, byte> img2 = new Image<Gray, byte>(@"abc.gif");
```

I want to perform operation on images like image addition pixel by pixel like ( without using inbuilt functions):

```
for (int i = 0; i < width1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < height1; j++){
        img2[i][j] = img1[i][j] + img2[i][j];
    }
}
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to alter the image, Pixel by Pixel then it's back to using the Image.Data property.

If you are using colour images it is important to note that it is a 3 Dimensional array containing Red, Green and Blue Data in layer 0,1,2 respectively. The following code will allow you to access data from the image and adjust it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < width1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height1; j++)
    {
        img1.Data[i,j,0] = img1.Data[i,j,0] + img2.Data[i,j,0];
        img1.Data[i,j,1] = img1.Data[i,j,1] + img2.Data[i,j,1];
        img1.Data[i,j,2] = img1.Data[i,j,2] + img2.Data[i,j,2];
    }
}
```

For the int<>Byte conversion error, you might need to cast the results to a (byte) (however you can assign int's to the Data providing there in range) i.e.

```
img1.Data[i,j,0] = (byte)img1.Data[i,j,0] + img2.Data[i,j,0];
```

this is done to tell .Net that you willing to accept data loss. Please note however you are adding two bytes from image data. There values are 0-255 so you could end up with a value of 0-510. To account for this you must normalise you results to the required 0 - 255 standard in images. i.e.

```
img1.Data[i,j,0] = ((img1.Data[i,j,0] + img2.Data[i,j,2])/0);
```

As you are using greyscale images you image data will only have 1 layer the code is similar in format however you only add the first layer 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < width1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height1; j++)
    {
        gray_image1.Data[i,j,0] = gray_image1.Data[i,j,0] + gray_image2.Data[i,j,0];
    }
}
```

The TDepth property allows you to alter the type of data held with .Data construct while some conversion are not supported doubles are, mainly because the way these are stored allow code to execute more efficiently with them. It is good practice to use this however not really essential.

Comment: Also, I just have grayscale images

Comment: I need to do it pixel by pixel :) Is there any way of indexing the images ?

Comment: It says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) and if I convert my Image<Gray, byte> img1 = new Image<Gray, byte>(@"xyz.gif");
to Image<Gray, int> img1 = new Image<Gray, int>(@"xyz.gif"); it says Convertion from Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgra, System.Int32> to Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, System.Int32> is not supported by OpenCV

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it a little clearer I hope you do not mind Russ your answer is pretty much there just have to wait for it to be reviewed. You should be fine using <Gray, byte> and assigning integers to it I have noted that you must in fact normalise the values your calculating remember a image pixel intensity is 0-255. If your value is greater than what the byte can store (255) then you will have problems. The error is designed to stop you losing the data. Cheers Chris

Comment: no no, it's fine, it was out of my depth in OpenCV, thanks! However, please post it as your own answer, so you can get your points!

Comment: It's fine I'm not in it for the points just to help take care